# How to use PostgreSQL bit_or function to aggregate column?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I wish to use PostgreSQL's `bit_or` function on several rows of a single column of my table, but I can't figure out the proper usage for this.

Suppose I have bitwise flags in my column `flags`, and the rows of interest hold the numbers 1 (`B00000001`), 2 (`B00000010`), and 13 (`B00001101`). I want the output to be 15 (`B00001111`).

What I've tried so far is as follows:

```
SELECT bit_or(SELECT flags FROM items);
-- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
SELECT bit_or((SELECT flags FROM items));
-- ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SELECT bit_or(array(SELECT flags FROM items));
-- ERROR:  function bool_or(integer[]) does not exist
SELECT bit_or(select array(SELECT flags FROM items));
-- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bit_or` is an aggregate function, like `sum` or `count`.

```
SELECT bit_or(flags) FROM items;
```